# Language of choice for CoreAudio

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, core-audio

I started to experiment with `CoreAudio` in Swift along with the 'Learning CoreAudio' examples which are written in Objective-C. What I noticed is that using Swift with `CoreAudio` is a little awkward...

For example I have to use the weird `UnsafeMutablePointer struct` for working with pointers and there is a lot of pointers in `CoreAudio`... Also when setting and getting properties you often use `sizeof()` but `sizeof()` returns an `Int` and the property getting and setting functions require an `UInt32` so I have to do something like `UInt32(sizeof(variable.dynamicType))` for this to work and there is a lot more weird stuff going on...

So I started to think if it is ok to write `Core Audio` code in Obj-C and all the application UI in Swift? Will I experience any performance bottlenecks using Obj-C instead of Swift? Or should I stick with the Swift for the sake of compatability and performance?

Answer (score 1):

Core audio is a C-based API, so it might feel pretty less ackward mixed with objC.

You can however write a High Level ObjC wrapper that fit your needs, meaning do all that you expect to achieve from CoreAudio, and then use it in a swift project by adding a bridge. The perf hit will be ridiculous (I know apple say swift execute faster than objC, but this is low level so it will be harmless.